# Python MYSQL Database update statement issue

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get the following Python MYSQL update statement correct(With Variables):

```
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect\
       (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd ="", db = "crawling")
except:
    print("Keine Verbindung zum Server")
    sys.exit(0)



cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("TRUNCATE meta;")
connection.commit()

cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE meta AUTO_INCREMENT =1;")
connection.commit()

for j in range(1, int(outerElements)):

    for i in range(1, int(innerElements)):

        partner_ID = 6

        location_ID = 20

        headline = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div["+str(j)+"]/div["+str(i)+"]/div/div[2]/h2/a").text

        price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div["+str(j)+"]/div["+str(i)+"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]").text[:-1]

        deeplink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productList']/div["+str(j)+"]/div["+str(i)+"]/div/div[2]/h2/a").get_attribute("href")





        print("Header: " + headline + " | " + "Price: " + price + " | " + "Deeplink: " + deeplink + " | " + "PartnerID: " + str(partner_ID) + " | " + "LocationID: " + str(location_ID))


        cursor.execute('''UPDATE meta SET (price_id, Header, Price, Deeplink, PartnerID, LocationID) \
          VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', ['None'] + [headline] + [price] + [deeplink] + [partner_ID] + [location_ID])

        connection.commit()


   cursor.close()
   connection.close()
```

When conducting the code, I´m getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/hmattu/PycharmProjects/untitled1/localhost_crawl.py", line  97, in test_sel
VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', ['None'] + [headline] + [price] +  [deeplink] + [partner_ID] + [location_ID])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 507, in   execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 722, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 640, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in    your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= (price_id, Header, Price, Deeplink, PartnerID, LocationID)
```

Can anybody help me out? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: That error doesn't match your code. It's saying you have an `=` before the parentheses in your UPDATE statement, which isn't in the code you have posted.

Comment: Also, `['None'] + [headline] + [price] ...` is nonsense: lists can have more than one item, that's the whole point. `['None', headline, price...]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
UPDATE meta SET (price_id, Header, Price, Deeplink, PartnerID, LocationID)
```

for

```
UPDATE meta SET (`price_id`, `Header`, `Price`, `Deeplink`, `PartnerID`, `LocationID`)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still not working: 
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('price_id', 'Header', 'Price', 'Deeplink', 'PartnerID', 'LocationID')          ' at line 1

Comment: use ` , not ' . 
`cursor.execute('''UPDATE meta SET (`price_id`, `Header`, `Price`, `Deeplink`, `PartnerID`, `LocationID`) \
          VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''' % ('None', headline, price, deeplink, partner_ID, location_ID]))`

Comment: @SeriousRuffy Where did you get the `() VALUES ()` syntax from? It is only valid for `INSERT` (and maybe `REPLACE`), but not for `UPDATE`.